# how to retrieve same set of results from google patents using bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I retrieve the same set of results from google patents if I do a keyword search, e.g. JAK

https://patents.google.com/?q=JAK&oq=JAK yields 12,416 hits

And how should I get the same results using bigquery?

```
SELECT
*
FROM
`patents-public-data.patents.publications` AS patentsdb,
UNNEST(abstract_localized) AS abstract_info
WHERE
LOWER(abstract_info.text) LIKE '%jak%'
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are seeking on StackOverflow. Your query returns 10,507 records. If there is a programming problem, we can help you. Duplicating Google's Patent Seach Engine is not something we can help you with.

Comment: Warning to readers: Running this query will process 800+GB, so keep costs in mind.

Comment: @user10167524 can you please add a narrower `WHERE` condition and what data is fetched from `patent` and not fetched from `BigQuery` (And a proof that this record exists in `BigQuery`). This will help answer your question